# Javascript error tracing and TRY and CATCH

Tags: javascript, error-handling, hta

Normally when an error occurs in a JavaScript script you get a nice message telling you on what line and in what file the error occurred. However, when using TRY and CATCH the message points to the location where the error is thrown.

Is there any way to use TRY and CATCH but still have the error message accurately point to where the error occurred?

[edit]

HTA applications are limited to IE 7. Even if you have later versions of IE installed, the HTA will still use IE 7.

Comment: Most web development tools will let you set a breakpoint in JavaScript code - just set a breakpoint on the content of your `catch` clause, and when the breakpoint is hit check the execution stack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `try-catch` isint for debugging purposes, it's for error handling. If you want to debug, just put a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of your `try-catch` block. Most browsers supports this statement as an inline breakpoint. You will then be able to set watches and execute the code line by line to track your issue.

However, note that in most modern browsers, the error object will have a [`stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) property that offers a trace of which functions were called, but it is non-standard.

Comment: My code is not running in a browser. It is for an HTML Application (.hta extesion on Windows). I don't think I can add breakpoints there.

Comment: @posfan12, Dont you run the application in IE?

Comment: Not sure whether to put the debugger statement at the beginning of the try block or the beginning of the catch block. (There are two blocks.) Also, I tried to run the following code but got "undefined" as a result.

try
{
 thisfunctiondoesnotexist()
}
catch (e)
{
 alert(e.stack)
}

Comment: @posfan12 I would put it at the beginning of the `try` block since you want to go line by line through these statements until one throws. Unfortunately, the `stack` property is non-standard and might not be present in all browsers.

Comment: OK I did this:

try
{
 debugger;
 thisfunctiondoesnotexist();
 debugger;
}
catch (e)
{
 debugger;
 alert(e.stack);
 debugger;
}

No dice.

Comment: @posfan12 Do not forget that `debugger;` is a statement, therefore you need `;` at the end. I am not even sure that IE supports that statement. If not you can just lunch the dev tools (F12) and put the breakpoint through the dev tools.

Comment: F12 is doing nothing either.

Comment: OK I did a quick browser check and the HTA file is reporting Internet Explorer 7. This is despite the fact I have IE 10 installed. I'm guessing the debugger and stack features aren't implemented in IE 7.